# Withholding data before save in Android

Tags: java, android, database, bundle

I'm not very sure of how to go about doing this, so I'm asking for some suggestions.

For starters, I have a activity that contains *ClassA.java* and *ClassB.java*.

*ClassA* has a button that, when tapped, goes into *ClassB*. *ClassB* then asks for input (1 **Integer** and 1 **String**), and then reverts back to *ClassA*, which displays what the user did on screen. I also want the user to be able to hit *'Save'* when everything is done, back in *ClassA*.

Problem is, how do I go about **storing that data** temporarily and permanently? *ClassB* does not return anything, so I'm thinking the temporary storage of data should be done in *ClassB*, brought over to *ClassA*, then saved in a database if the user hits *'Save'*.

**Am I doing this the right way?**

Also, am I right to call Android ***Bundles*** 'temporary storage'? They save the user's input temporarily, and if the application closes the Bundle is deleted (nothing is saved), right?

So would storing strings and integers in a ***Bundle*** and then transferring them to a ***database*** afterwards be theoretically correct and also be a possible way to tackle this problem?

Or does anyone have a **better solution**?

Comment: I might be answering my own question here, but I just want to clear any doubts before moving onto coding -- cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to withhold  values permenantly, i.e.., Even after restarting the application, you want the data back to your application, then go for SharedPreferences

[Shared Preferences](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html)

If you want to with hold temporarily and you want to pass the value from one Activity to another activity, You should pass intent and get the values from the bundle in the target activity.

[Intent](http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2011/05/27/passing-data-with-an-intent/)

Comment: no, I want to withhold it temporarily, then if the user hits 'save', i want to save it permanently.

Comment: Ok, If you want to withhold temporarily, store it in a variable, when you hit 'Save', store it in a Shared Preferences, so it will be available until you uninstall the app

Comment: any suggestions for sharing data across different activities, though? you cant just throw a variable from ClassA to ClassB.

Comment: Only, Shared Preferences is the solution

Comment: I will, just letting it fester for a bit to see if there are any other contributions.